# How to get Devise session timeout callback?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, devise

Is there a way to get a callback/ process some action when a user's session times out with Devise?

The plain old overriding the DeviseSessionsController doesn't work:

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

  def destroy
    #do something
    super
  end

end
```

This only works when a user logs out, which makes sense since it doesn't seem like a controller is called on session timeout. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found that doing Warden.before_logout was the best solution:

```
# app/models/user.rb

Warden::Manager.before_logout do |user, auth, opts|
  #fdsafdsafdsa
end
```

Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be any way to do this with pure Devise.

Comment: I've added this callback, but while it's being called when a user manually logs out, it doesn't seem to be called when a user's session times out. Is there something more I need to do to have this callback work on timeout?

Comment: Hmm that's weird. To my knowledge it should work if you -- for example -- try to access a page and the app notices your session has timed out. If it isn't working I'd suggest doing some more digging. However take note that session timeouts do not fire events, if that's what you're trying to capture...

Answer (score 0):

```
before_filter :destroy_custom, :only => [ :destroy ]


def destroy_custom 
    # Do your thang
end
```

I was able to do this on new method. I am guessing it is possible to do the same with destroy as well. The callback could be called inside the devise_custom or devise_custom itself could be the method where you want to execute something before destroy.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that this doesn't work on timeout. It seems like session#destroy isn't actually called when the user's session expires

Comment: Sorry, spoke too soon.

It doesn't seem to actually call the destory method. Found this blog. Hoping it helps.

http://madkingsmusings.blogspot.com/2011/05/session-timeouts-on-rails.html

Answer (score 0):

The issue is still up to date. The easiest solution I could muster for this is to override the `timedout?` method in the `User` model.

```rb
def timedout?(args)
    retval = super(args)
    if retval 
        # Do whatever you need to do here
    end 
    retval
end
```

`record.timedout?` gets called before signing out is trigger in the event of the timeout
https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/main/lib/devise/hooks/timeoutable.rb#L27C5-L27C5